# Bootstrap 3 sub dropdown menu opened unnecessary

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a menu with submenu but when I hover the menu, submenu is opened itself. Here is my site where I try to make sub menu http://ilkereksioglu.com/

And my HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="kopie"><a href="#">Dropdown2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown2 Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown2 Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown2 Link 3</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown2 Link 4</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="kopie"><a href="#">Dropdown2 Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown2 Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown2 Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown2 Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown2 Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
                </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: oh sorry I added `</ul>` but still same problem

Comment: In the custom-fun.js there is code for `.dropdown` hover where you are finding all elements with class dropdown and fading it. `$('.dropdown-menu', this)` will return two uls. You need to write something like this `$('> .dropdown-menu', this)`